# Calculate the probability of "at least one"?

Tags: probability

> A major electronics manufacturer has determined that when one of its televisions is sold, there is $0.08$ chance that it will need service before the warranty period expires. 
>   Suppose a retailer sells four televisions on a particular Saturday. What is the probability that none of the four will need service prior to the warranty expiring?

What I did is that I calculated the probability of at least one TV needs repair, (which is the opposite of none of four need repair): $0.08+0.08+0.08+0.08 = 0.32$

Then I calculate the probability of none of four need repair: $1 - 0.32 = 0.68$

On the other hand, my friend calculated using the percentage the TV does not need repair, which is $ 0.92 $. And got the probability of none of four need repair: $0.92x0.92x0.92x0.92 = 0.716$

I feel like both ways is right, but why are the answers different? Did I or my friend do it wrong?

Comment: If he sold forty televisions instead, would the probability that one need repair be $0.08+\cdots+0.08=3.2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your friend is correct.

The probability that *none of the four TVs needs repair* is: each TV's individual probability of not being repaired, multiplied together.

$0.92 \cdot 0.92 \cdot 0.92 \cdot 0.92 = 0.92^4 = .71639296$

You cannot add the probabilities.

A helpful resource may be the responses to this Quora question ["How to know when to add and when to multiply probabilities"](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-know-when-to-add-and-when-to-multiply-in-questions-based-on-probability), particularly the response by Nisha Arora. She writes:

> If your problems has words like "or", "either", "atleast" or their synonyms, you need to 'ADD' favorable cases & hence the probabilities. [learn more about addition theorem & mutually exclusive cases] 
>   If your problem has words like "and", "both", "all" or their synonyms, you need to 'MULTIPLY' favorable cases & hence the probabilities. [learn more about multiplication theorem & dependent events]